# Why nest an <svg> element inside another <svg> element?

Tags: svg

Why would a demo such as this: http://jsbin.com/ejorus/2/edit, have an `<svg>` element nested inside another `<svg>` element?

```
<svg class="graph">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g transform="translate(30,0)">
            <!-- ... -->
        </g>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

The JS Bin is a modified version of [the demo](http://meloncholy.com/static/demos/responsive-svg-graph-1/) in this blog post: http://meloncholy.com/blog/making-responsive-svg-graphs/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're right (as you say in [Mr. Alien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890342/648802)) that both SVG elements have the same relative positions, and indeed the graph displays fine without the outer SVG.

The reason I added it is because the JavaScript (which I needed to stop the labels getting squished) uses the SVG element's [transform matrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined) (caused by the applied `viewBox` attribute) to unscale the text.

Unfortunately the returned matrix doesn't take account of transformations applied to the SVG element itself, so I needed to get the transform matrix relative to an outer element that used the [initial coordinate system](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InitialCoordinateSystem) instead. Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 This is helpful. Thanks! I am trying to come up with a resonsive SVG graphing solution for my web app. In [your article](http://meloncholy.com/blog/making-responsive-svg-graphs/) you mention [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). Would you reccommend it? I have a related question on the subject where I was trying to use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848688/responsive-svg-line-graph-with-raphael Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: D3 is great - it's really powerful and flexible, though it does have quite a steep learning curve. I'd definitely [give it a go](http://christopheviau.com/d3_tutorial/). That said, if you want something fairly common, you may well get results more quickly from other graphing libraries. I haven't used Raphael, so can't comment on that. You may also want to take a quick look at [this web stats](http://meloncholy.com/blog/using-d3-for-realtime-webserver-stats/) thing I made (not responsive unfortunately, but uses D3). There's a [demo here](http://bits.meloncholy.com/mt-stats).

Answer (score 41):

> Nesting SVG elements can be useful to group SVG shapes together, and
>   position them as a collection. All shapes nested inside an svg element
>   will be `positioned (x, y) relative to` the `position (x, y)` of its
>   enclosing svg element. By moving the x and y coordinates of the
>   enclosing svg element, you move all the nested shapes too.
>
> Here is an example where two rectangles are nested inside two svg
>   elements. Except for the colors the two rectangles have the same
>   definitions for `x, y, height`, and `width`. The enclosing svg
>   elements have different x-values. Since the `x-position` of the
>   rectangles are interpreted relative to their enclosing svg elements
>   `x-position`, the two rectangles are displayed at different
>   x-positions.
>
> - By Jakob Jenkov

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg x="10">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
        style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
  </svg>
  <svg x="200">
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
        style="stroke:#009900; fill: #00cc00"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

[Credits](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-element.html)

Comment: @chrmod Did you see a link which says **Credits** at the very bottom of the answer?

Comment: Would this be allowed, multiple SVG's? This would make positioning a lot easier if you can use a couple `svg` as a bit of a framework.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Why can't we use the `<g>`? I think the main use case for it is exactly what you have described. Incidentally, what do you think the differences are b/w grouping elements with `<g>` and `<svg>`?

Comment: @GauravRamanan I just answered the question which was why nest svg inside svg :)

Comment: I meant doesn't the same logic apply to <g> ?

Answer (score 7):

You can define a new `viewport` & `viewbox`. With this option, you can use  [relative positions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) like as `css`. For more information, you can see this online [article](http://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/nesting-svgs/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Nested SVG</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <rect x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" style="fill: dodgerblue;" />
        <svg x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%">
            <rect x="25%" y="25%" width="50%" height="50%" style="fill: tomato;" />
        </svg>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but would the <g> element be just as good as a nested <svg> element?

Answer (score 0):

I am about to do this for an entirely different reason: website implementation efficiency.

I have several SVG files that I insert into my web page after downloading them via AJAX.  I want to consolidate them into one file because that's better for downloading.  I could do this with a text file and then insert the SVG text into a web page element's `innerHTML` property, but .svg files offer two additional advantages over .txt files:

1) The standard .svgz format allows you to store pre-zipped files on the web server, no need for `mod_deflate`. SVG files zip very efficiently, I'm seeing 70-85% compression.

2) The web browser parses the SVG outside of my javascript code, hopefully more efficiently.  To insert the svg element into the HTML, I use the parent element's `insertBefore` or `appendChild` method instead of `innerHTML`.