# Edit svg using JavaScript and place a PNG inside an SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, svg-edit

How can I edit an SVG same like fill color and other methods of SVG I want to place an SVG/PNG inside an SVG at some specific path/group of SVG, How come it is possible can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other libraries out there but I used Snap on a project to edit SVGs based on user selections. http://snapsvg.io/

As for the embedding question, there are other stackoverflow questions that answer that [Why nest an <svg> element inside another <svg> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890292/why-nest-an-svg-element-inside-another-svg-element)